# How to simulate key press event on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I need to trigger keypress event with given char code in facebook status field using chrome extension. Is there correct way to do it.

I tried with following code.but seems it not working.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
    if(message.pressEnter){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabs[0].id }, "1.0");
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabs[0].id }, 'Input.dispatchKeyEvent', { type: 'keypress', windowsVirtualKeyCode:13, nativeVirtualKeyCode : 13, macCharCode: 13  });
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabs[0].id }, 'Input.dispatchKeyEvent', { type: 'keyDown', windowsVirtualKeyCode:13, nativeVirtualKeyCode : 13, macCharCode: 13  });
            chrome.debugger.detach({ tabId: tabs[0].id });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging

Comment: any luck with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the chrome debugger API's Input.dispatchKeyEvent, what element is the target element? Regular event dispatching requires specifying the target element.

Also, events dispatched using the normal javascript dispatch API aren't trusted, so they don't trigger default behaviors. E.g. using javascript to dispatch a letter A to a text input does nothing by the spec.

So, start by checking to see if the event that is dispatched is trusted and finding which element it targets.